# Crystal reports returning 404 on api url after displaying some reports

Tags: c#, angular, asp.net-mvc, api, crystal-reports

I am using Crystal reports in my C# ASP.net Web API project with angular. Crystal reports works fine for few times and displaying properly but after displaying some reports it return this errors

```
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)  
API URL : `http://localhost/api/Reports/RptComplaintDetail`
```

I am disposing and closing report documents objects in finally block. And also increase  PrintJobLimit to 9999 but nothing work, still getting error after sometimes or generating reports.

```
    public async Task<HttpResponseMessage> RptUnAuthAccessLog([FromBody] RptUnAuthAccessResquestModel objModel)
        {
            //Create Report Document Object
            ReportDocument rd = new ReportDocument();

            try
            {

                if (!ModelState.IsValid)
                {
                    string ErrorMsg = ErrorModelState(ModelState);
                    ErrorLogs("Invalid Model State. Report not executed, Controller Name : ReportsController, Method Name : RptUnAuthAccessLog, Report Name: User Un-Authorized Access Report, ", ErrorMsg);
                    return Request.CreateErrorResponse(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest, "Invalid Model State.");
                }
                //User Authentication
                objResMsg = await UserAuthentication(objModel.Token);
                if (!objResMsg.Status.Equals("Success"))
                {
                    return Request.CreateErrorResponse(HttpStatusCode.Forbidden, "Your Session Expired, Please Login again.");
                }

                //fill Report Dataset
                var dsUnAuthAccess = await BIReports.RptUnAuthAccessLog(objModel);
                //Get Office Details
                var officeDetail = BICommon.GetOfficeInfo();

                ValidationResponseModel objValidation = new ValidationResponseModel();
                objValidation = TokenManagerJwt.ValidateToken(objModel.Token);


                var response = new HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.OK);
                Stream stream;
                if (dsUnAuthAccess.Count != 0)
                {
                    rd.Load(Path.Combine(HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("~/Reports"), "docUnAuthAccessLog.rpt"));
                    rd.SetDataSource(dsUnAuthAccess);
                    rd.PrintOptions.PaperSize = CrystalDecisions.Shared.PaperSize.PaperA4;
                    rd.SetParameterValue("FromDate", objModel.fromDate);
                    rd.SetParameterValue("ToDate", objModel.endDate);
                    //rd.SetParameterValue("Department", objModel.DepartmentName);
                    rd.SetParameterValue("OfficeName", officeDetail.OfficeName);
                    rd.SetParameterValue("OfficeAddress", officeDetail.OfficeAddress);
                    rd.SetParameterValue("GeneratedBy", objValidation.FullName);
                }
                else
                {
                    string crt = "From Date: " + objModel.fromDate.ToShortDateString() + ", To Date: " + objModel.endDate.ToShortDateString();
         // debugger find error on this path sometime                  rd.Load(Path.Combine(HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("~/Reports"), "docDefaultTemplate.rpt"));
                    rd.PrintOptions.PaperSize = CrystalDecisions.Shared.PaperSize.PaperA4;
                    rd.SetParameterValue("rptCriteria", crt);
                    rd.SetParameterValue("rptName", "Un-Authorized Access Report");
                    rd.SetParameterValue("OfficeName", officeDetail.OfficeName);
                    rd.SetParameterValue("OfficeAddress", officeDetail.OfficeAddress);
                    rd.SetParameterValue("GeneratedBy", objValidation.FullName);
                }
                //Convert Report to PDF and Render back to Request
                stream = rd.ExportToStream(CrystalDecisions.Shared.ExportFormatType.PortableDocFormat);
                stream.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
                response.Content = new StreamContent(stream);
                response.Content.Headers.ContentLength = stream.Length;
                response.Content.Headers.ContentDisposition = new System.Net.Http.Headers.ContentDispositionHeaderValue("attachment");
                response.Content.Headers.ContentDisposition.FileName = "UnAuthAcess_" + DateTime.Now.ToString("dd-MM-yyyy-hh-mm-ss") + ".pdf";
                response.Content.Headers.ContentType = new MediaTypeHeaderValue("application/octet-stream");
                response.Content.Headers.Add("Access-Control-Expose-Headers", "Content-Disposition");
                response.Content.Headers.Expires = new DateTimeOffset(DateTime.Now);
                return response;
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                ErrorLogs("Report not executed, Controller Name : ReportsController, Method Name : RptUnAuthAccessLog, Report Name: Un-Authorized Access Report, ", ex.Message.ToString());
                //return Request.CreateErrorResponse(HttpStatusCode.NotFound, "Sorry, unable to generate un-authorized access report at this moment. Please contact your system administrator.");
                return Request.CreateErrorResponse(HttpStatusCode.NotFound, "Sorry, unable to generate report at this moment. Please contact your system administrator.");
            }
            finally
            {
                rd.Close();
                rd.Dispose();

            }
        }
```

Comment: 404 means your url is wrong. It has nothing to do with your code (if you only don't trhow custom 404 exception)

Comment: It work fine and display reports properly but sometime it return "HttpErrorResponse" when i generate reports.

Comment: Do you have HttpErrorResponse or 404?

Comment: POST http://localhost/api/Reports/RptComplaintDetail 404 (Not Found)

Comment: i also get this in error key `error: Blob
size: 104
type: "application/json"`